# Invertible Ideal in Noetherian Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been spending hours reading proof to a lemma but am stuck, I would love to get some pointers from you gurus to get it going, see below. (The original proof is in one big paragraph but I delineate it by line items for easy reading.)

LEMMA: Assume that *R* is a noetherian integral domain and that each nonzero prime ideal of *R* is invertible. Then each nonzero ideal of *R* is invertible.

PROOF: (1) By way of contradiction, assume that *R* possesses a nonzero ideal of *R* which is not invertible.

(2) Among the nonzero ideals of *R* which are not invertible we pick a maximal element and call it *S*. (Recall that such a maximal element exists, since we are assuming that *R* is noetherian.)

(3) As we are assuming that all nonzero prime ideals of *R* are invertible, and *S* is not invertible, therefore *S* is not prime.

(4) Since *S* is not prime, therefore there exist ideals *T* and *U* of *R* such that *S* $\subseteq$T, *S $\subseteq$U*, *T$\neq$ S $\neq$ U*, and *TU $\subseteq$S*. (Recall this is actually just the negation of the lemma that says that if *S* is prime then there exist ideals *T* and *U* of *R* such that *S $\subseteq$T*, *S $\subseteq$U*, *T$=$S* or *S$=$U* and *TU* $\subseteq$*S*.)

(5) Since S *$\subseteq$U* and *S$\neq$U*, **the maximal choice of *S* forces *U* to be invertible.**

(6) Thus ...

I am totally stuck on line #5, "... the maximal choise of *S* forces *U* to be invertible" and I would love to get help from you. I think I have included all the necessary background to understand this lemma, but please let me know if I skipped anything. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We chose $S$ to be a maximal member (under inclusion) of the set of non-invertible ideals. This means that $S$ is not strictly contained in any other non-invertible ideal.

Therefore any ideal $U$ strictly containing $S$  must be invertible - since if it were non-invertible, then $S$ would be strictly contained in another non-invertible ideal, contradicting the maximality of $S$.

Since $S \subsetneq U$, we must have that $U$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help!